# Angular2 rc1, new router and passing data

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

Used to have, with deprecated router, a few components that routed to the same component:

**Some Component**

```
import {Component, Injector} from 'angular2/core';
import {IDataServiceSome} from './IDataServiceSome';
import {RouteData} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'Some',
    templateUrl: './Some.html'
})
export class Some {
    Model;
    DataService: IDataServiceVendor;

    constructor(routeData: RouteData, injector: Injector) {
        var dataServiceToken = routeData.get('DataServiceToken');
        this.DataService = injector.get(dataServiceToken);
        this.Model = DataService.getSomeModel();
    }
}
```

**IDataServiceSome**

```
export interface IDataServiceSome {
    getSomeModel(): Object;
}
```

**e.g. Comp1 but there are Comp2, Comp3, etc...**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfigs, Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';

import {DataServiceSome1} from './IDataServiceSome1';

@RouteConfigs([
    { path: '/Some', name: 'Some', component: Some, data: { DataServiceToken: DataServiceSome1 } }])
@Component({
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [DataServiceSome1],
    selector: 'Comp1',
    template:
    `<div>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        <h1>Comp1 routed to Some</h1>
    </div>`
})
export class Comp1{

}
```

As you might have guessed, there are many data services that implement `IDataServiceSome` and many components that route to `Some`. The choice of which data service is used, comes from any component that routes to `Some` component using a data token known to `injector`. With rc1 release and new router, the `RouteData` is deprecated or removed, but how is this scenario implemented moving forward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait for Angular2 to add the `data` back. In my case, a service that decides which data service is needed could be injected via DI. I found that to be an overkill, it simply is a passing parameters just like it's in URL query strings. The only difference was that the parameter shouldn't be visible to user for a better experience.

Source:

http://www.github.com/angular/angular/issues/8515

Answer (score 3):

**update**

RC.4 brings `data` back

- Passing data using routes

```
{ path: 'parent/:id', data: {one: 1}, resolve: {two: 'resolveTwo'}}
```

and access it using

```
this.route.snapshot.data
```

or

```
this.route
      .data
      .subscribe(v => console.log(v));
```

See also the Plunker at https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9757#issuecomment-229847781

**original**

Parameters can be passed like:

- with a router link

```
<a [routerLink]="['/crisis-center', {bar: 'foo1'}]">Crisis Center</a>
```

- with `router.navigate()`

```
this.router.navigate(['/crisis-center', {bar: 'foo2'}]);
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/fKSnUzM4aLg1Q8ftkFAp?p=preview)

`app/app.component.ts` contains the links and code where parameters are passed, `app/crisis-center/crisis-center.coomponent.ts` contains the code where the parameter is read and written to the console.

I don't think there is support for extra data anymore.

Comment: But not supporting `data` means you either have to use query string or route parameters. Both of those are part of 'tour of heroes' example. In my case, i don't really want the user to see the data service token as part of the URL and there is no reason for them to. So i don't quite understand why `data` is removed.

Comment: The routes are just URL and component name. There are also no route names anymore. If you need to pass other data that is not reflected in the URL, just use a shared service.

Comment: duh! so you'll need a service to tell the `Some` component what data service to use? even doing so, how hard it's to figure out which component was the last one that set the data service which to be used by `Some`? debugging nightmare. On the other side, a mediator might help but i totally see it as an unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Sure, but it also solves many other problems the old router had.

Comment: Is there anywhere i could see and learn about those problems? personally didn't find anything wrong with it.

Comment: That's a pretty major change - I'm glad I saw this before I went ahead and implemented data approach on the router-deprecated module. Any rough idea when would the current router be relatively feature complete so that we can drop the deprecated beta version for good?

Comment: I got the impression they're working hard on it. Most things are in place already. A few smaller bugs were reported. I guess with RC.2 it will be good enough to actually use it.

Comment: Nice - thanks for the info @GünterZöchbauer! You know, I was thinking how to redesign the router-data code that I was planning to implement and actually, at least in my case, the services approach makes all the sense in the world. It provides a lot more elegant solution than to the pure passing of objects. I think the main issue to newcomers (like myself) is to get into the Angular2/DI mindset and get into the habit of viewing issues not as "ok here i need this variable so I need to insert it from somewhere" but rather as "what standalone module can take care of this everywhere in my code"

Comment: See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8515 Sounds like `data` will come back.

Comment: Actually, it seems I have to use `this.route.snapshot.params.` to get at the data...

Comment: Since RC.4 it's possible to use `router.navigate` method and passing data that can be retrieved when user get back to from this page ?

Comment: You can get data from `ActivatedRoute` or from the router traversing routes to find the route segment that holds the data.