# angular2 router.navigate along with data - hide data from URL

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router

I want to navigate to some page in angular2 along with data, while doing so data is coming in URL. Is there a way to pass data without showing it in URL?
I'm using the following code:

```
this._router.navigate('test',{hugeJsonData: JSON.stringify(bigJson)});
```

Comment: navigating reload its so if you dont want in url just  stringify and add in local storage

Comment: The next update (RC.4) will bring `data` back to the router. This allows you to pass data that will not modify the URL. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37077094/angular2-rc1-new-router-and-passing-data/37078196#37078196

Answer (score 0):

```
let link = ['Home'];                     this.__router.parent.hostComponent.isLoaded = "Anshuman";
this._router.navigate(link);
```

and you will get it in child as

```
this.__router.parent.hostComponent.isLoaded
```