# How to deal with application structure without route system

Tags: angular

since Angular2 router is RC, I decided to build an application without Routing, but I didn't find how to call different component, let me know if my approach is correct since I don't want to use router.

index.html has a reference (tag) for my app.component.ts (my main component.. I bootstrap it on main.ts)

but inside this app.component.ts I want to call another component, how to proceed? I tested add another component in app.component template, but with multiple component will be very hard to maintain which component render each time...

need help on this multiple component structure:

main component ------ (links) ----> user registry component ----- (links) -----> forgot password component

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the application architect on my project. Anyways, your best option is to actually use that router and live up the pain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37077094/angular2-rc1-new-router-and-passing-data).

Although since it wasn't my decision and most likely it isn't yours, the simplest alternative is to hide and show component(s) based on flags when links are clicked. So you'll need a flag for user registry component and another for forgot password component. When a link is clicked, you'll set the appropriate flag to true.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: 
    '<app>
        <p>
            i'm the app!
            <a href="#" (click)="activateUserRegistry()">User Registry</a>
            <a href="#" (click)="activateForgotPassword()">Forgot Password</a>
        </p>
        <div [Style.display]="isUserRegistryActive ? 'block' : 'none'">
            <userRegistry></userRegistry>
        </div>
        <div [Style.display]="isForgotPasswordActive ? 'block' : 'none'">
            <forgotPassword></forgotPassword>
        </div>
    </app>'
})
export class App {
    activeFlags = {
        ...
        isUserRegistryActive: Boolean = false;
        isForgotPasswordActive: Boolean = false;
        ...
    }

    deactivateAll() {
        for(var prop in this.activeFlags) {
            this.activeFlags[prop] = false;
        }
    }

    ...
    activateUserRegistry() {
        this.deactivateAll();
        this.activeFlags.isUserRegistryActive= true;
    }
    activateForgotPassword() {
        this.deactivateAll();
        this.activeFlags.isForgotPasswordActive = true;
    }
    ...
}
```

As you can see, it's pretty messy code and hence why Angular2 team came up with router in the first place. Another messy approach could be the use `Renderer` to render content dynamically, which is even worse the above code. As a developer, you need to know how the code will look like, given or taken from above code.

Additionally, router doesn't just route to components. It also detaches the DOM element and removes event handler bindings to improve performance. If you choose to go the messy route, you might want to keep an eye on all of that.

Disclaimer: haven't tested this code, it's only to prove concepts.

Comment: Hi Hani, since we don't have the release for Router so far, we are gonna implement this way at least to proceed with components stuff, maybe we add Util helpers to control when to display/hide etc... I appreciate your suggestion, and also @micronyks suggestion, is pretty good hear other professionals about this new stuff.. thank you

Comment: @humbs no problem. By the way, the whole angular2 is RC or beta, so not using router because it's RC didn't make much sense. Just something to look out for.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you want to redirect from one page to another, router/routing is needed.

2) You can go with `DynamicComponentLoader(DLC)`, you might end doing stuffs but complex one.

3) As @Hani has suggested, but you will have to manage lots of things.

Whats the problem with router? `Angular2 router` is very poweful. You should try it.

Comment: Hi Micronyks thanks for the answer, the problem is that probably this system will go to production early and is a decision of my team to do not bring unstable stuff to production, to be honest I am not frontend expert but I like t look for alternatives... your suggestions were very welcome but I believe we are gonna wait a little bit more fr Angular 2 router release, or maybe test and approve the RC. thank you