# Pass objects during router navigate

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

I would like to pass objects during router navigate to the target component.
Currently I am using routeParams and I stringify my objects to strings. This approach works, but I don't like this solution. How would a better solution look like?

```
export class Overview {
    //import {Router} from "@angular/router-deprecated";
    constructor(private router:Router) {}
    goToElementComponent(elem:Element) {
        this.router.navigate(['ElementDetail', {elem: JSON.stringify(elem)}]);
    }
}
export class ElementDetail {
    // import {RouteParams, Router} from "@angular/router-deprecated";
    this.elem : Element;

    constructor(private routeParams:RouteParams) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        var elem = JSON.parse(this.routeParams.get("elem"));
        if (elem) {
          this.elem = elem;
        } else {
          this.elem = new Element();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With the next update (RC.4) `data` will be supported again. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37077094/angular2-rc1-new-router-and-passing-data/37078196#37078196

Comment: Thanks. I will wait for RC.4 and then update this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach would be to store the temporary params in a Shared Service

You'd have to inject the service into constructors, in order to write/read your object params

Comment: But do not put it in the providers (if you do this, it will create a new object and all data will be lost).. . You also could use an EventEmitter to pass/emit the data and subscribe to it in the target.. .

Comment: I have included the ElementDataService into main.ts bootstrap. Besides the service just consist of one property and getter and setter methods. It works currently for me. How can it be done better?

Answer (score 7):

```
//Note: router:Router and route:ActivatedRoute
//send object from one component (its independent parent-child relationship with //another component): 
  bill = {
    'customerName': "RAJESH",
    'billNo': "A230",
    'date': "23/12/2020",
    'address': "AGRA",
    'itemDetails':"HUSQVANA VITIPILEN",
    'grandTotal': 2500000
  }
this.router.navigate(['/billingpdf',{billing:JSON.stringify(this.bill)}])

//accessing this object into another component like this:
//-------------------------------------------------------
this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('billing') //store this variable if you want use further
                                    or
this.route.snapshot.paramMap.getAll('billing')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using NavigationExtras parameter of navigate method.
NavigationExtras object should have state parameter where you can put your custom data:

```
this.router.navigate(['/route-to'], {
      state: {
        someData: { name: 'Some name', description: 'Some description' },
      },
    });
```

In targeted component we receive data this way:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
 this.dataFromRoute = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state?.['someData'];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Pass object in the queryParams like the following:

```
this.router.navigate(['/my-route'], {queryParams: myObject});
```

Answer (score -3):

see http://ngcourse.rangle.io/handout/routing/routedata.html there is workaround to do this in javascript

Comment: spam link, do not open